# How to publish solution with class library projects in IIS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis, asp.net-web-api, publish

I have an Asp.Net Web Api solution with 3 class library projects that are referenced from the main project. I have published the main project to another server on site - MySite/Main. I am unable to figure out how to publish the class library projects to location like so -

```
MySite/CL1
MySite/CL2
MySite/CL3
```

This shall enable the main project to reference them properly. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

When you build your web project all the referenced libraries are being copied to the bin folder (check for yourself). This folder is also being published.

If you use IIS it will automatically look for assemblies in the bin folder so you shouldn't worry about making the folder structure to be the same as in your local environment.

So the only thing you should worry about is referencing libraries properly.
The website project is the only one which should be published. You don't need to publish class libraries (I don't think you can do this using Visual Studio)

Comment: Yup! Figured that out from another post. Thanks.