React Vite Web Api with ASP.NET Core app deployed, but axios fails with a 404 error
I created a full-stack Web API application where the frontend is ASP.NET Core with React.js (I use react vite) and the backend is a C# class library.
I succeeded in deploying the frontend on IIS to loacalhost:80. When I browse the site from IIS, I am greeted with the loading icon that I created, which shows me that the frontend is deployed correctly, but the issue is that the loading never stops, because the axios request to "/api/account/getcurrentuser" gives a 404 error. The backend fails to find http://localhost:80/api/account/getcurrentuser.
Here is the detailed error info.
This happens for all axios requests. The server returns a 404 saying that it fails to find the resource. The physical path that it's looking in is C:\Website\EDIConverterDemo\wwwroot\api\account\getcurrentuser. The wwwroot folder is the one in my project's deployed folder. Is it supposed to look there and I need to add something, or is it directed to the wrong place?
The app works perfectly when run locally (not on IIS), and the route in my controller matches the url in my axios GET request.
I thought I may have needed to deploy the backend class library as well, but some research on that end told me that I don't need to deploy it separately.
I think my issue is a react issue, specifically because I am using vite.
This is my vite.config.js file.
Can it be CORS issue or an issue with the vite proxy? When I run my project locally (not on IIS), the react frontend is based on port 3000, while all calls that start with "/api" are rerouted to my controllers, which are hosted on port 7264. Do I need to change the ports in the proxy? The
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    strictPort : true,
    proxy: {
      '/api' : {
        target: 'https://localhost:7264',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,enter image description here
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, '/api')
      }
    }
  }
})

Or can it be an issue with the backend?
This is the controller that /api/account/getcurrentuser is supposed to go to:
namespace EDIConverterWeb.Web.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AccountController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("getcurrentuser")]
        public User GetCurrentUser()
        {
            //here is some code that returns null if no user is signed in
            //otherwise, returns the currently logged-in user (object)
        }
    }
}

This is my Program.cs file:
Is something misconfigured which is causing the controller to be missed?
namespace EDIConverterWeb.Web
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static string CookieScheme = "EDIConverter";
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieScheme)
           .AddCookie(CookieScheme, options =>
           {
               options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
               {
                   OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
                   {
                       context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                       context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                       var result = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { error = "You are not authenticated" });
                       return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
                   }
               };
           });

            builder.Services.AddSession();

            // Add services to the container.

            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseSession();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); ;

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}

This is how my web.config file looks:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

UPDATE:
I don't think it's an issue with React, can you help me figure out how to get the API part of my app running on deploy?
ANOTHER UPDATE:
Here is a link to a reproductible demo

Have you deployed frontend and backend both on iis? and how you deployed the project? what is your iis configuration for the site/ application? could you try setting the   target url with the iis hosted site url. have you tried accessing your api url directly? could you enable failed request tracing rule in iis. is it possible for you share the small reproducible demo with us

could you help answer all the question asked in my previous comment

I looked into deploying the projects separately, but since my backend project is a class library, I don't need to deploy it separately, as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164428/how-to-publish-solution-with-class-library-projects-in-iis. I tried setting the target url in the vite.config.js to my hosted site url: "http://localhost:80", but I got the same 404 error in my project. When I try accessing my api url directly in the browser, I am given the same 404 as shown above in the post. I haven't tried failed request tracing, but I am looking into installing and enabling it.

so as per your description i understood that frontend ASP.NET Core with React.js (I use react vite) and the backend is a C# class library. from the error it seems iis is checking the api request to the same wwwroot folder of the site you hosted on the iis. could you check your console log for more detail. iis failed request tracing document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/troubleshoot-arr-using-frt-rules.

it would be great if you share small reproducible sample with us. as there is lots of thing going on in your project it will be difficult to guide you. where your api is hosted? are you running locally?as your proxy will not work in the iis i am trying to understand where your request for the api is going so that i can guide you to help you to redirect your api request to the correct location.

Here is the video demo of the deployment process: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n73JzE_aI0QJVIvqXtVrEbNs-_KWR5zB/view?usp=sharing

i got some overview now. Could you collect the fiddler logs and check that. asi am not able to reproduce the issue at my side. as i said if possible could you share the reproducible sample project with us. and could you manually try to access the api path and see the result. i just noticed you have set the wwwroot folder as the site folder path which is react site and the api url is .net core web application which is not deployed on iis that’s why you are getting 404 error

The reason that I deployed the wwwroot folder is because if the physical path points to my applicaation's deployment folder, I get a 403- Forbidden error when browsing my site from IIS. I did some research on deploying react and was told to face the project to the wwwroot folder- I guess that's why only the React is deployed and not the rest of the project. What should the physical path be if I want to deploy the whole thing?

you could try to add this below code in your .csproj file and after that publish the project from visual studio as folder and use that published root folder path instead of wwwroot in iis.

<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build" />  <ItemGroup>   <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**" />   <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">    <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>    <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>    <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>   </ResolvedFileToPublish>  </ItemGroup> </Target>

I added a link to the post with a reproductible demo of the project.
Thank you.

so i used your project and published the web application which is "EDIConverterWeb.Web" from the visual studio in folder and used the same folder path in iis as site root folder. i can see the site is running with login page: image

Can you explain in more detail? Did you use the 'publish to iis' option in visual studio or 'publish to folder'? Thank you.

When I publish to folder and use it as the physical path for the site I am given this error. Also, what did you put as the web config?

@JalpaPanchal, do you have any updates? Thank you.

i can not see the error snapshot you shared

This is my web.config file: <configuration>   <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">     <system.webServer>       <handlers>         <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />       </handlers>       <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\EDIConverterWeb.Web.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />     </system.webServer>   </location> </configuration>

The error image I showed before was a 403 forbidden error. I got this error when I use my web.config file (one specifically for react), and make the folder with the published files the physical path for the site (not the wwwroot folder).
When I use your web.config file, I am given this error when browsing the site in IIS-
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
@JalpaPanchal, can you share a demo or more specific information to help me publish it the same way as you? Thank you.

i will post the detailed steps as an answer to guide you

1)Open you project in the visual studio, Right click on the EDIConverterWeb.Web project and click on Publish
2)In the Target choose Folder option-> Next
3)Create New folder and give name to it -> click Finish

4)Now Click on the Publish to publish the site and wait until it finish
5)Now Open iis -> Click on site-> Add new website

6)Set the published folder as the site root folder

Note: No need to add anything extra code for a now in the web.config file. Just use new publish folder

I followed your exact steps and I got this same error:
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Also, what did you do for the bindings of the website? Does that make a difference?

@Anonymous have you installed hosting bundle and runtime? Could you share error snapshot

Thank you. I didn't install it before, because there are other sites running from IIS on this server, so I assumed it was installed previously.
I installed it and now it's working perfectly. Until now I used localhost, but after I get somewhere to host this, where do I input the information to connect to the host? Do I do it directly into IIS? Until now I was using the 'Publish to IIS' option by publish. With the 'Publish to folder' option, where do I put in the host name, site name etc.?

@Anonymous  to set the hostname you could go to the iis server, select your site-> from right hand side action pane select the bindings option and you can modify it based on your requirement
